# How do you retrieve the title of a plot device window?

Tags: r, plot

You can set the title of a plot device window with

```
windows(title = "The title")
#or equivalently
x11(title = "The title")
```

How you retrieve the title from a plot device window?

`names(dev.cur())`, `attributes(dev.cur())`, `str(dev.cur())` and `unclass(dev.cur())` don't reveal anything useful.

Comment: I am not trying to be smart or anything, but cant you just

`plotname="The title";               `
`windows(title = plotname); `
`plotname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be possible from device properties cause it's window property.

Under windows you could try mess with `names(getWindowsHandles())` which gives me:

```
> names(getWindowsHandles())
[1] "R Console"
[2] "The title (ACTIVE)"
[3] "R Information"
```

E.g. for active device `grep("\\(ACTIVE\\)$", names(getWindowsHandles()), value=TRUE)` return the title.

---

It was easier than I thought:

```
getTitle <- function(dev=dev.cur()) {
    all_pointers <- getWindowsHandles(which="R", minimized=TRUE)
    all_pointers <- sapply(all_pointers, deparse)
    to_find <- deparse(getWindowsHandle(dev))
    if (to_find=="NULL") {
        warning("Device not found")
        NULL
    } else {
        names(all_pointers)[to_find==all_pointers]
    }
}
```

Now some tests:

```
> getTitle()
Warning in getTitle() : Device not found
NULL
> windows(title="Test window one")
> getTitle()
[1] "Test window one (ACTIVE)"
> getTitle(3)
Warning in getTitle(3) : Device not found
NULL
> windows(title="Test window two")
> windows(title="Test window three")
> sapply(dev.list(), getTitle)
                     windows                      windows                      windows 
"Test window one (inactive)" "Test window two (inactive)" "Test window three (ACTIVE)"
```

Comment: Bravo!  This is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

---

You could do that, but that approach would get cumbersome when dealing with multiple plots. I suspect Richie is more interested in how/where R stores the title information once you send it to the graphics device—as am I.